# Can't Retrieve the OUI (Weekly Unemployment Claims in Reverse Chronological Order with most recent data first

Tags: api, labor

I'm trying very hard to get this thing to work.   I'm using the AddOn "importJSON" from NoDataNoBusiness on a Google Sheet.  I've got it to a point where I can import data from the OUI, but it is in date order ascending, so I'm getting the stuff going all the way back to 1967 first.   And it limits to 99 rows.

So - I need reverse the order of this and essentially get the last rows.   I'm trying to sort in descending order by date, and I've been following the guidlines for the sort statement - but the documentation is COMPLETELY unclear on how the $ sign and ? sign works, what goes where, and in what order.

My importJSON cell statement looks like this:
**=transpose(importJSON($C$1, $C$2))**

Here are the contents of $C$1
**https://api.dol.gov/V1/Statistics/OUI_InitialClaims/unemploymentInsuranceInitialClaims?KEY=mykey**

Here are the contents of $C$2 which filters (selects) the columns I want to look at:
**nonSeasonallyAdjustedInitialClaims, seasonallyAdjustedInitialClaims, nonSeasonallyAdjustedContinuingClaims, seasonallyAdjustedContinuingClaims, week, id**

I'll attach a sample of the results so you can see how perfectly it's working ...

BUT

I can't get the data in the order I want it.

At the URL for the DOL, they have information about sorting, and they show this:
**http://api.dol.gov/V1/FORMS/AgencyForms?$orderby=FormNumber desc**

...but when I try to place this in the call line with the key, I'm hosed.   In my particular case, my order by statement, following this logic, would look like this ...

**[https://api.dol.gov/V1/Statistics/OUI_InitialClaims/unemploymentInsuranceInitialClaims?$orderby='week'?KEY=mykey](https://api.dol.gov/V1/Statistics/OUI_InitialClaims/unemploymentInsuranceInitialClaims?$orderby=%27week%27?KEY=mykey)**

It fails.  I've tried every imaginable permutation and combination.  No 's around the word week, only one? mark, I mean - I'm going nuts here trying to get this to work - and I can't.

Can ANYONE help me please so that I can have this run the way it's supposed to?   I'll be in your debt!